# Lisp sum of multiples of 3

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

so I'm new to LISP and I was wondering how I could find the sum of numbers that are divisible by 3.
Here's what I have done so far:

```
(defun sumel (li)

 (cond 
  ((null li) 0)

 ( (zerop (rem (car li) 3))  (+ (car li) (sumel (cdr li))))

 )

)
```

A little hint to what I'm doing wrong would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hanve the case where the list is empty and when you actually find a multiple of 3, but what happens if it is a nother number you should skip? You have do default term so Common Lisp will return `nil`. Eg your code works like this:

```
(defun sumel (li)
 (cond 
  ((null li) 0)
  ((zerop (rem (car li) 3))  
   (+ (car li) (sumel (cdr li))))
  (t nil))) ; when not a multiple of 3 we are finished, return nil
```

Try evaluating `(cond)` and you'll see it is the same as `(cond (t nil))`.

You fix this by adding just `(sumel (cdr l))` as the alternative. It should evaluate to the sum of the multiples of the rest of the list, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a different approach which utilizes the large standard library of Common Lisp (`remove-if-not` and `reduce` in this case)

```
(defun sumel (list)    
    (reduce '+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (zerop (rem x 3)))
                              list)))
```